# Blocking 3D audio in Blender Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, audio

Is there a way to 'block' or stop 3D audio so that in one room I can hear it but in another besides it I can't without ending it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt way, but with python you could easily script a visibility check between the source and camera and use that to fade the volume.

Comment: One problem with this is that I need the sound to spread across many connected rooms and be blocked by a ceiling, so the visibility check wouldn't really work.

Comment: Have your ceiling have a specific game property and use a raycast with X-ray enabled.